# JButton open an image

Tags: image, button, icons, jbutton

im designing a program for my school that displays the teachers schedules at the click of a button. I have everything figured out but how to open an image by clicking on the specific teachers name. here is some of my code any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
       `JButton gabster = new JButton("Mrs. Gabster");
         gabster.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel gabster = new JPanel();

        }
    });`
```

i need to have the button open a new image from my workspace

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)   
{
  ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("picture.jpg");
  JLabel picture = new JLabel(pic);
  panel.add(picture);
}
```

Create a method for when the button is clicked.